# Azure Select Account shown when user already logged in session

Tags: java, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

We've migrated from adal4j to msal4j in our java web applications.

All works well but the big difference is that when the user is already logged (maybe in other applications but same browser session) we always see the "select user" page and the user is not logged automatically and redirected to redirect uri as before with adal4j.

This is how we redirect to autentication page:

```
private static void redirectToAuthorizationEndpoint(IdentityContextAdapter contextAdapter) throws IOException {
    final IdentityContextData context = contextAdapter.getContext();

    final String state = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    final String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    context.setStateAndNonce(state, nonce);
    contextAdapter.setContext(context);

    final ConfidentialClientApplication client = getConfidentialClientInstance();
    AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters parameters = AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters
            .builder(props.getProperty("aad.redirectURI"), Collections.singleton(props.getProperty("aad.scopes"))).responseMode(ResponseMode.QUERY)
            .prompt(Prompt.SELECT_ACCOUNT).state(state).nonce(nonce).build();

    final String authorizeUrl = client.getAuthorizationRequestUrl(parameters).toString();
    contextAdapter.redirectUser(authorizeUrl);
}
```

I've tried to remove `.prompt(Prompt.SELECT_ACCOUNT)`
but I receive an error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

•   You might be getting the option for selecting the user account after switching to MSAL4J in your browser even after the SSO is enabled because either `clearing the token cache is enabled in your code` or **MsalInteractionRequiredException** option is thrown and specified accordingly due to which the **application asks for a token interactively**.

Thus, please **check which accounts information is stored in the cache** as below: -

```
 ConfidentialClientApplication pca = new ConfidentialClientApplication.Builder(
            labResponse.getAppId()).
            authority(TestConstants.ORGANIZATIONS_AUTHORITY).
            build();

  Set<IAccount> accounts = pca.getAccounts().join(); ’
```

Then, from the above information, `if you want to remove the accounts whose prompts you don’t want to see during the user account selection such that the default account should get selected and signed in automatically, execute the below code` by modifying the required information: -

```
   Set<IAccount> accounts = pca.getAccounts().join();

    IAccount accountToBeRemoved = accounts.stream().filter(
            x -> x.username().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    UPN_OF_USER_TO_BE_REMOVED)).findFirst().orElse(null);

    pca.removeAccount(accountToBeRemoved).join();
```

•   And for the **MsalInteractiveRequiredException** class in the code, kindly refer to the below official documentation link for the **AcquireTokenSilently** and other reasons responsible for the behaviour. Also, refer to the sample code given below for your reference regarding the same: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-java#msalinteractionrequiredexception

```
   IAuthenticationResult result;
    try {
        ConfidentialClientApplication application = 
     ConfidentialClientApplication
                .builder("clientId")
                .b2cAuthority("authority")
                .build();

        SilentParameters parameters = SilentParameters
                .builder(Collections.singleton("scope"))
                .build();

        result = application.acquireTokenSilently(parameters).join();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        if(ex instanceof MsalInteractionRequiredException){
            // AcquireToken by either AuthorizationCodeParameters or DeviceCodeParameters
        } else{
            // Log and handle exception accordingly
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks KartikBhiwapurkar-MT I'll consider your suggestions for the future.
For my problem, after many tests, i had only to remove .prompt(Prompt.SELECT_ACCOUNT)
The problem was that when i removed this option I had in browser sessions two different logins in azure tenants.

Comment: Ok...that's great to hear that your issue was resolved. Thank you.